# Makefile remove files

Tags: bash, makefile, pattern-matching

For a schoolproject I try around with makefiles. First I create the files with

```
install: main.c
    gcc -asve-temps main.c
    @if test ! -d bin/; then mkdir bin; else : fi
    mv a.out $(shell pwd)/bin/
    chmod 555 ./bin/a.out
```

Now I want to clear the project:

```
clear:
@if test -d *.[osia]; then rm *.[osia] else : ; fi
@if test -d a.out then rm a.out; else: ; fi
```

Running make install works fine. Running `make clear` produces the error code:

```
/bin/sh: 1: test: main.i: unexpected operator
```

and does not remove the requested files. I want to delete all the `*.o *.s *.i and *.a` files by running the `make clear` target using the pattern given above avoiding the error `cannot remove ... : no such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` expects a single argument; when you pass it a glob, it's getting a bunch of them. Something like `find` will work in this case:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.[osia]' -delete
```

Or, why check if the file exists at all?

```
rm -f *.[osia]
```

Couple of other notes: if you don't have an `else` clause in your if statement, don't include it. Read up on the `test` command; you certainly don't want to be using `-d` if you're looking for files. And, you can use the variable `$PWD` in place of running a subshell to get it.